# reprex can't find the ref() function

Tags: r

```r
x <- list(1:10)
ref(x)
#> Error in ref(x): could not find function "ref"

tracemem(x)
#> [1] "<0000000017E74B50>"

x[[2]] <- x
#> tracemem[0x0000000017e74b50 -> 0x00000000164836e8]:

ref(x)
#> Error in ref(x): could not find function "ref"
```

I wanted to make a reproducible example with reprex. But it can't find the function ref. I loaded the lobstr package. Why is that happening can you tell me?

Comment: You say you loaded the lobstr package but don't show us that you did.  Are you sure it installed and loaded correctly?

Comment: Did you load it or just install it? Make sure you run `library(lobstr)` or try `lobstr::ref(x)` directly.